# KLEE: ERROR: unknown intrinsic: llvm.objectsize.i64.p0i8

Tags: llvm, klee

I encountered the error "KLEE: ERROR: unknown intrinsic: llvm.objectsize.i64.p0i8" when running KLEE on a program.

I know that I should add support for it in the IntrinsicCleaner pass. But I failed to find the documentation for this intrinsic function. Does anybody know the purpose of this intrinsic function?

Below is the line of LLCM code that involves the function:
`%6 = call i64 @llvm.objectsize.i64.p0i8(i8* %5, i1 false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right in the [LLVM documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-objectsize-intrinsic):

```
declare i64 @llvm.objectsize.i64(i8* <object>, i1 <min>)
```

> The llvm.objectsize intrinsic is designed to provide information to the optimizers to determine at compile time whether a) an operation (like memcpy) will overflow a buffer that corresponds to an object, or b) that a runtime check for overflow isn’t necessary. An object in this context means an allocation of a specific class, structure, array, or other object.

Comment: What does the 'p0i8' mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'll extend Marco's answer to address Dingbao's question. 'p0' denotes a pointer into address space 0; 'i8' indicates an 8-bit integer. See [the LLLVM language reference](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout).